# SQL Select/View : Can I display data with a "reorganization" of the table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, ssms

I don't really think it's possible to do that in a SQL query but I'm trying to extract some data and I'd like "reorganize" the structure of the table (put row data as columns).

It's hard to explain so there is a example, this is my table :

```
MONTH | CODE | VALUE
Jan   | ABC  | 100
Jan   | DEF  | 200
Jan   | GHI  | 200
Feb   | ABC  | 400
Feb   | DEF  | 250
Mar   | GHI  | 450
```

And this is what I want :

```
CODE  | Jan  | Feb  | Mar
ABC   | 100  | 400  | null
DEF   | 200  | 250  | null
GHI   | 200  | null | 450
```

Is it possible to display data like this with a SQL query?

NB : I'm using SQL Server 2008 (with SQL Management Studio)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.

```
SELECT Code,
MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH='Jan' THEN VALUE ELSE NULL END) AS JAN
MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH='Feb' THEN VALUE ELSE NULL END) AS Feb
MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH='Mar' THEN VALUE ELSE NULL END) AS Mar
FROM table_name
GROUP BY Code
ORDER BY Code
```

Comment: It helps me a lot thank you ! But The MAX() gives me false results. I tried SUM() and it was ok. Whatever, thank for your help, I didn't know the expression "CASE".